# Is a label-tag inside a button-tag valid and / or has any UX- / ergonomic-reasons?

Tags: buttons, labels, html5

I am checking an application and I found this in HTML DOM:

```
<button type="submit">
  <label>Submit</label>
</button>
```

I have never seen this before and asking myself if this is valid for HTML5 or any other DOCTYPE Definition?
Moreover can anyone suggest why there is the `label` inside the `button` from the view of UX / ergonomics? Or is there no need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The  element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the  element, it toggles the control.

[w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Maybe this W3C recommendations may help you too: [Labeling Controls](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/)

Comment: So it is definitely wrong to use the `Label` inside a `button`.

Comment: It looks so. The only example I could find where you really need a label for a button is when the button itself is not described properly, does not contain wording that fits to its purpose.

Comment: There is an example in the Mozilla Dev website:  "In the example below, a button is styled to look like a typical "close" button, with an X in the middle. Since there is nothing indicating that the purpose of the button is to close the dialog, the aria-label attribute is used to provide the label to any assistive technologies.   <button aria-label="Close" onclick="myDialog.close()">X</button> "